# Почему не удаляется динамически созданный элемент?

Tags: jquery

Ребят, привет. Не срабатывает закрытие динамически созданного блока.

Подскажите, как правильно здесь реализовать?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.em-panel-close', function() {
    $(this).parent('.edit-me-panel').remove();

    // В консоли клик виден, но remove() не выполняется
    console.log($(this).parent());
  });

  $('.edit-me').on('click', function(e) {

    // Здесь создаем элемент
    $(this).append('<div class="edit-me-panel"><div class="em-panel-close">Закрыть</div></div>');

    // Здесь children() срабатывает нормально, хотя тот же элемент.
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit-me-bg')) {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Редактируем фон');
    } else {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Не редактируем фон');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper edit-me edit-me-bg">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `$(this).parent('.edit-me-panel')` и `$(this).parent()` это несколько разные вещи

Comment: @andreymal, Не, тут в другом ошибка: всплытие события клика

Comment: Консоль в обоих случаях выдает одно и то же. И remove() не срабатывает в обоих случаях.

Comment: @Grundy если всплытие отключить, то все равно не удаляется. Но по сути всплытие дает только повторное добавление элементов при  клике  на закрытие

Comment: @ДанилСысоев, `remove` срабатывает, просто сразу добавляется **еще один** элемент

Comment: @teran, добавил ответ с пояснением :)

Comment: @Grundy я пока хотел отредактировать вопрос и подключить там jquery, у меня почему-то не скрывался-добавлялся и постоянно добавлялись блоки :) но в конце рабочего дня не надо в такое вникать, так что я забил :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаваемый элемент с классом `edit-me-panel` лежит внутри элемента `edit-me`, поэтому при клике на `edit-me-panel` сначала срабатывает ее обработчик клика, и удаляет элемент, затем событие *всплывает* и выполняется обработчик клика `edit-me` и заново добавляет элемент, поэтому кажется, что ничего не удалялось.

Для предотвращения этого, можно воспользоваться [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), что запретит всплытие. Но в данном случае этого недостаточно, так как обработчик закрытия висит *на самом деле* на элементе `body`, это означает, что он выполняется *после* обработчика открытия, и делать отмену всплытия уже поздно.

Для решения нужно уменьшить путь до элемента, на который вешать обработчик закрытия, например повесив его так же на `edit-me`

Например:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('.edit-me').on('click', '.em-panel-close', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // останавливаем всплытие
    $(this).parent('.edit-me-panel').remove();
    // В консоли клик виден, но remove() не выполняется
    console.log('close click');
  });

  $('.edit-me').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('edit click');
    // Здесь создаем элемент
    $(this).append('<div class="edit-me-panel"><div class="em-panel-close">Закрыть</div></div>');

    // Здесь children() срабатывает нормально, хотя тот же элемент.
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit-me-bg')) {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Редактируем фон');
    } else {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Не редактируем фон');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper edit-me edit-me-bg">Click me</div>
```

Альтернативное решение: вешать обработчик непосредственно на создаваемый элемент

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('.edit-me').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('edit click');
    // Здесь создаем элемент
    $('<div class="edit-me-panel"><div class="em-panel-close">Закрыть</div></div>').find('.em-panel-close').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // останавливаем всплытие
        $(this).parent('.edit-me-panel').remove();
        console.log('close click');
      })
      .end()
      .appendTo(this);

    // Здесь children() срабатывает нормально, хотя тот же элемент.
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit-me-bg')) {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Редактируем фон');
    } else {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Не редактируем фон');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper edit-me edit-me-bg">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Понял, и правда, внимательность подвела. Спасибо большое. А за альтернативный вариант, отдельное спасибо =) Без наводки сам так бы вряд ли написал =)

Comment: @ДанилСысоев, здесь скорее не внимательность, а неочевидность того, какой обработчик когда выполняется, в общем случае для делегированных событий лучше навешивать обработчики на один контейнер, тогда они будут выполняться в порядке добавления

Answer (score 0):

Должно удаляться то, что создается при клике?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.em-panel-close', function() {
    $('.em-panel-close').parent().remove();

    // В консоли клик виден, но remove() не выполняется
    console.log($(this).parent());
  });

  $('.edit-me').on('click', function(e) {

    // Здесь создаем элемент
    $(this).append('<div class="edit-me-panel"><div class="em-panel-close">Закрыть</div></div>');

    // Здесь children() срабатывает нормально, хотя тот же элемент.
    if ($(this).hasClass('edit-me-bg')) {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Редактируем фон');
    } else {
      $(this).children('.edit-me-panel').append('Не редактируем фон');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper edit-me edit-me-bg">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Да, сейчас работает так как нужно. А Вы что-то еще изменяли кроме содержимого метода parent?

Comment: Плохое решение, так как если на странице будет несколько элементов с `.em-panel-close` то удалятся все, а не только тот, по которому кликнули

Comment: @ДанилСысоев только 4 строку изменил. Работает для _этой конкретной_ задачи.

Comment: @Grundy возможно я неправильно мыслю, но зачем сначала создавать элемент, потом **искать** его? Можно ведь при создании элемента добавить его в какой-нибудь объект (или массив), потом просто удалить нужный?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n не понял вопроса

Comment: @Grundy при создании динамического элемента добавлять его в эдакую _базу созданных элементов_, а на клик вешать _база.нужный-элемент.remove()_ ?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, такая база уже есть: DOM называется, нет нужды дублировать еще и в коде, из клика идет _прямой_ доступ к элементу, поэтому не нужно идти в базу для его поиска